# How do you call a function from a click on a cell in a TableView with a TableViewController using a delegate in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` from which I need to call a function in another ViewController when a user clicks on a cell in the TableView. The problem is I can not assign the delegate to self in the ViewController that contains the function. The problem is with the following line:

```
let messageTableVC = UITableViewController() as! MessagesTableViewController
messageTableVC.messageDelegate2 = self
```

The let statement builds with no error, but the app crashes on that line with this error when run:

> Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewController' (0x1b77cb588) to
>   'MFPApp.MessagesTableViewController' (0x100719e08).

`MessagesTableViewController` is a `UITableViewController`. I've tried casting to other ViewController types but nothing else will build.
Here is the relevant code:

MessagesTableViewController

```
    protocol openMessageDelegate2 {
        func addNewTab2()
    }
class MessagesTableViewController: UITableViewController, IndicatorInfoProvider {
    var messageDelegate2: openMessageDelegate2!

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            print("cell clicked")
            messageDelegate2?.addNewTab2()

        }

}
```

In second VC:

```
class MainViewController: ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        let messageTableVC = UITableViewController() as! MessagesTableViewController
        //let messageTableVC = MessagesTableViewController()
        messageTableVC.messageDelegate2 = self
}

}

extension MainViewController: openMessageDelegate2 {

    func addNewTab2(){
        print("new tab")
        addNewVC = "yes"
        self.reloadPagerTabStripView()
        self.moveToViewController(at: childViewControllers2.count-1)
    }
}
```

Comment: The above looks odd, but as a start: `MessagesTableViewController` is _not_ a `UITableViewController`, and that's exactly what the error is telling you. If you actually want an instance of `MessagesTableViewController` you should create an instance of that instead: `let messageTableVC = MessagesTableViewController()`.

Comment: you want that when you click on tableview cell, it push to another view controller?

Comment: @Terjie, that compiles but the function does not execute

Comment: @Khawar, when a cell is clicked a function should execute from another view controller

Comment: @MarcMcLean If your function isn't executing you need to show the code.  You should have implemented the `didSelect` delegate method in your custom tableViewController, and within that function you should be calling your `messageDelegate2` methods to notify the delegate.

Comment: Executing a function in another controller is bad design. If it is a stand alone function then put it in a class of its own.

Comment: @MarcMcLean Please share tabBar controller identifier and class name.

Comment: @Kharaw, ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController but that is not related to the problem. If you just create an instance of a VC using let messageTableVC = MessagesTableViewController() the delegate function does not execute

Comment: @ryantxr, the function creates an new VC and adds it to an array for use with XLPagerTabStrip

Comment: Are these view controllers coming from a StoryBoard?

Comment: @ryantxr, yes. I tried

Comment: @ryantxr, I tried         let messageTableVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MessagesVC") as! MessagesTableViewController
        messageTableVC.messageDelegate2 = self This compiles and runs with no error but does not execute the function

Comment: @ryantxr, the TableView is in a TableViewController. I'm wondering if I put the TableView in a ViewController would that make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Since `UITableViewController` is **NOT** a subclass of `MessagesTableViewController` you can't cast it as such.

If you are simply trying to instantiate a `MessagesTableViewController` just change that line to:

```
let messageTableVC = MessagesTableViewController()
messageTableVC.messageDelegate2 = self
```

Comment: It took a couple of readings to understand your answer. While correct once I parsed it properly, your *"But since..."* paragraph immediately after the first line of code seems at first to apply to that line of code. So at first reading it seems wrong. Perhaps a little edit will make it clearer on first read. I would suggest removing "But" and then moving *"Since UITableViewController is NOT a subclass of MessagesTableViewController you can't cast it as such."* to the start of the answer.

Comment: @creeperspeak, that compiles but the function does not execute

Comment: @rmaddy I really appreciate the feedback.  I certainly don't want my answer to be confusing.  I edited and removed the confusing bits.

Comment: @MarcMcLean The problem is with your delegate methods.  Please post your code.

Comment: @creeperspeak, I created a test app and when I use let secondVC = ViewController2() the func does not execute but with let secondVC = segue.destination as! ViewController2 the func works fine. The same problem here but let messageTableVC = UITableViewController() as! MessagesTableViewController is not correct. There must be another way to instantiate messageTableVC